# Tracking database changes on related models... Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

We are trying to detect the changes in Laravel related models at attribute level, as we have to keep audit trail of all the changes which are made via the application.

We can track the changes via isDirty method on the Eloquent model for single model that is not related to any other model, but there is no way that we can track the changes on the related eloquent models. isDirty doesn't work on related models attributes. Can some one please help us on this?

Update to original question:

Actually we are trying to track changes on the pivot table that has extra attributes as well defined on it. IsDirty method doesn't work on those extra attributes which are defined in the pivot table.

Thanks

Comment: Every model has its own isDirty method right, but why you dont implement functionality according to every model. and one thing you need to check its relation model by `->relations`.

Comment: what type of changes you trying to detect by the way? CRUD?

Comment: Actually we are trying to track changes on the pivot table that has extra attributes as well defined on it. IsDirty method doesn't work on those extra attributes which are defined in the pivot table. Yes we are detecting CRUD changes as we have to create audit trail.

Comment: Isn't this something that needs to be in the database, like a trigger that copies changed rows to a table that only allows inserts? That could track data changes, no matter what application was used. (I like to help, even on old questions)

Answer (score 3):

As much I understand your question, It's can achieve through Model Event and some sort of extra code with current and relation model.

**Laravel Model Events** 
If you dont want to use any additional stuff, you can just use the Laravel Model Events (that in fact Ardent is wrapping in the hooks). Look into the docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various
>   points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: creating,
>   created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted,
>   restoring, restored.
>
> Whenever a new item is saved for the first time, the creating and
>   created events will fire. If an item is not new and the save method is
>   called, the updating / updated events will fire. In both cases, the
>   saving / saved events will fire.
>
> If false is returned from the creating, updating, saving, or deleting
>   events, the action will be cancelled:

Finally, reffering to your question you can utilize the above approaches in numerous ways but most obviously you can combine it (or not) with the Eloquent Models' **getDirty()** [api docs here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getDirty) method and **getRelation()** [api docs here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getRelations) method

It will work for example with the saving event.

```
Model::saving(function($model){
    foreach($model->getDirty() as $attribute => $value){
        $original= $model->getOriginal($attribute);
        echo "Changed";
    }
    $relations  =  $model->getRelations();
    foreach($relations as $relation){
      $relation_model = getRelation($relation);
      foreach($relation_model->getDirty() as $attribute => $value){
        $original= $relation_model->getOriginal($attribute);
        echo "Relation Changed";
      }
    }
    return true; //if false the model wont save! 
});
```

**Another Thought might help you. when you saving**

`save()` will check if something in the model has changed. If it hasn't it won't run a db query.

Here's the relevant part of code in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model@performUpdate`:

```
protected function performUpdate(Builder $query, array $options = [])
{
    $dirty = $this->getDirty();

    if (count($dirty) > 0)
    {
        // runs update query
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

The `getDirty()` method simply compares the current attributes with a copy saved in `original` when the model is created. This is done in the `syncOriginal()` method:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}

public function syncOriginal()
{
    $this->original = $this->attributes;

    return $this;
}
```

---

check model is dirty `isDirty()`:

```
if($user->isDirty()){
    // changes have been made
}
```

Or check certain attribute:

```
if($user->isDirty('price')){
    // price has changed
}
```

I did not check this code but hopeful to use as your answer by thoughts, if you have any confusion to deal such requirement or something need to optimize or change please let me know.